# I accidently typed the command sudo chmod -R 0444 /

Tags: 20.04

I accidentally typed the command sudo chmod -R 0444 / now my system won't boot and when I click recovery mode, I get end kernal panic Attempted to kill init exit code=0x00000100.

Comment: This is simply a fatal error. You need to reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

There's no going back or solving this.

All you can do is try running a live ubuntu or some linux dist, access your files push them to cloud or drive, to ensure you don't loose your data and then reinstall OS

Comment: How do I push my files to a cloud drive?

Comment: prepare a usb with linux, once you boot your system with the usb there will be an option to run or test os "named as Live" or try ubuntu
try that option this will boot your system and you can move your files to drive as there will be a browser as well

Comment: Where will the option be? I'm using a dell r210 ii PowerEdge server

Comment: in the boot menu once you insert the USB , reboot your server, it should come up by pressing f12 in dell, during boot , be caution don't hit the install now, just go with TRY UBUNTU

Comment: It's an external hard drive that I plug in using a USB right?

Comment: NO, you need to prepare a flash/Pen drive with linux.
Using some different system(laptop or desktop)
download the image from ubuntu site and burn it to flash drive using (win32 on windows or rufus or etcher on linux)

Don't use your hardrive for that.

Comment: Is there a video or step-by-step instructions on how to do this?

Comment: you can find multiple on youtube just google how to create a bootable drive for ubuntu

this might help : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9DR-b7c5MP4

Comment: This will help my backup my old files right?

Comment: No, It will help you prepairing a bootable flash drive with linux
Then you need to boot your server with this flash drive and choose TRY UBUNTU

Comment: I already have that, how do I back up the hard drive so I don't lose important files. I have a disk drive and a disk with the data of the operating system. I just need to back up the current files of the operating system that is messed up. I have 2 Minecraft servers and no backup for it. How do I back up the hard drive to my laptop?

Comment: In this case just boot your server with live mode.
using this 
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#3-boot-from-usb-flash-drive

once you get it running go to files and you will see your disk from the server.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-nS660EmYM

try this, sjip the steps you already have
Once booted you will get browser and drive push your files to cloud or drive using browser